# How to swap multiple values in a large list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large list of data points ({{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}...}) that I need to swap the elements of for each point ({{b,a},{d,c},{f,e}....}). This is specifically for a curve-fit, so the data needs to change, e.g. it isn't enough to plot them on different axes, and there are a lot of data points, so manually swapping each one isn't an option. What would be the fastest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If `alist = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}` then `Reverse /@ alist` would do the job.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much

Comment: Try also this: `{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} /. {x_, y_} -> {y, x}`.

Answer (score 2):

We can `Reverse` the level 2.

```
list={{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
Reverse[list,{2}]
```

> {{b, a}, {d, c}, {f, e}}